# Getting a not enough input arguments error

Tags: matlab, function, input, quantum-computing

I'm trying to plot the Yukawa Potential in Matlab and I want to have my program go through user inputs for the values alpha (called alph in my program) and l. The values I need to use are 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 for alpha with values of 0, 1 and 2 of l for each value of alpha. I know I could set up a loop for this but it doesn't have to be pretty and I want to test the values one at a time. Anyway I keep getting an error after I input the values for alpha, the error I keep getting is in my function, saying that I don't have enough input arguments. The output should be the T matrix, the Hamiltonian matrix and a plot of the first 10 eigenfunctions.

I've tried going in and simply defining alpha as the numbers I want to look at and the program works fine with displaying the output I'm looking for. I just want to be able to change the values for alpha without having to change the program itself. I haven't had any problems with the l inputs.

```matlab
r = linspace(0.05,19.95,1999)
n = 1999
dr = 0.05
a = full(gallery("tridiag",n,1,-2,1))
T = -0.5*a/(dr^2)
l = input('Input a value for l.')
alph = input('Input a value for alpha.')
v = arrayfun(@(r) yuk_pot(r,l),r);
V = diag(v)

H = T + V
[O,D] = eig(H);

 plot(r,O(:,1),r,O(:,2),r,O(:,3),r,O(:,4),r,O(:,5),r,O(:,6),r,O(:,7),r,O(:,8),r,O(:,9),r,O(:,10))

function v = yuk_pot(r,alph,l)
   v = (-exp(-alph*r)/r) + 0.5*(l*(l+1)/(r^2));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

your function `function v = yuk_pot(r,alph,l)` has 3 input arguments.

you call it with 2 arguments (`r` and `l`)
`v = arrayfun(@(r) yuk_pot(r,l),r);`

what about the second `alph` argument?

Comment: Works like a charm now thank you, sorry it was such an easy fix, it just slipped my mind.